# width and height of an Stretched Image

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Can I get the `Height` and `Width` of an `Image`, if it has been **Stretched** by `UniformToFill`?

I tried `Width` and `Height` properties but they are always `NaN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know the dimensions of the image control, this is the way:

```
double theHeight = this.ActualHeight - img.Margin.Top - img.Margin.Bottom;
double theWidth = this.ActualWidth - img.Margin.Left - img.Margin.Right;
```

(`img` is the image control name in the code above, and in the codes below)

---

And if you want to know actual size of image (before it being stretched) you may try this:

```
BitmapSource SourceData = (BitmapSource)img.Source;
double imgWidth = SourceData.PixelWidth;
double imgHeight = SourceData.PixelHeight;
```

*(I've Found this [here](http://www.vistax64.com/avalon/55688-wpf-image-source-real-size.html#post269573))*

---

Also this will get you the dimensions of image after resizing (But before uniforming):

```
double actWidth = img.ActualWidth;
double actHeight = img.ActualHeight;
```

So, one of those variables (`actWidth` or `actHeight`) must be equal to image control dimension, and the other will be higher than it.

---

Please note that the second and the third codes are not working if you call them in `Window_Loaded` event, since images are not loaded at that moment. You should use it after everything is loaded.

Comment: why do you ask two questions and then answer both of them? Was the questions really necessary?